# Nginx rewrite doesn't work without a subdomain?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, configuration

I'm trying to rewrite a particular url, but it doesn't seem to work unless a subdomain is included as part of the url.  For example, given the following:

```
server {
  server_name .example.com ;
  listen  80  default;
  root  /usr/share/nginx/www/example/public;
  rewrite ^ /test redirect;
}
```

`http://www.example.com/original` correctly redirects to `http://www.example.com/test`.  But `http://example.com/original` does not?

I'm running nginx 1.0.11 (custom built) on a Fedora box if that helps.

EDIT: PS - I've also tried `server_name  example.com  *.example.com` with no luck.

Comment: Increase your `error_log` verbosity to `notice`, and turn on `rewrite_log`. See if anything relevant shows up in the error logs, and post the relevant sections here. (You can also add the same directives to the http block to see that the error is not originating elsewhere).

Comment: You probably have another server block interfering, please paste all your server blocks.

Comment: Wow, I'm a total moron.  Sorry for all the noise.  Basically, I edit /etc/hosts so that I can type "www.example.com" into my browser and have it point to 127.0.0.1 rather than the 'real' "www.example.com".  I do this so I can write things like an nginx config with ".example.com" rather than having to type "localhost" on one machine and then ".example.com" on the production server.  The only problem is that I didn't add example.com to /etc/hosts!  So it was pointing to the 'real' server which I was obviously not changing.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try redirecting any request to www.example.com go to example.com:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 80 default;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    location /original/ {
        rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/test redirect;
    }
    # rest of config here;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck.  The 1st rewrite happens as expected (`www.example.com` -> `example.com`), but rewrites inside of the `example.com` directive still don't seem to work ...

Comment: Made a change in the example.com rewrite block. And forgot to add, the root line is not needed in the www block.

Comment: Does the above example work on your machine?  I.e., just wondering if you tried it out ... it still doesn't seem to redirect anything (even with the location directive) on my machine.  Maybe I'll try it out on another machine and see if I have the same problem.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: @ktr the above example is the same one I use on production servers. Redirect the www to the none-www domain.